View length when using Draw Cube (add cube) tool
I do hammer-style level design in Blender, and I want to know the dimensions of cubes/blocks i create using the "add cube" tool that allows you to draw the cube.
It's actually quite nice how you can snap it to grid and orient it to the surface, or any axis. The only issue is that I want to be able to tell the width/length/height of a cube WHILE i'm creating it. The grid floor is not a solution, because any complex environment will always be above or below the grid, and the grid will be hidden by other geometry anyway.
I would like to be able to know what part of blender's code to edit, or how to write an addon so that I could know the length of the sides of the cube as I'm creating it.


FWIW. I don't know anything about hammer-style level design. If you have Developer Extras checked in the Display section at the top of Edit->Preferences->Interface and you right click on the Add Cube tool, you get options to View Source, Copy Python Command and for the online Blender and Python manuals sections regarding it. But, they cover creating the cube only. It doesn't look to me like there is a way to display dimensions in the way that you want to.
